# Get request_token and request_secret from Foursquare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foursquare

I want to get my access_token and access_token_secret from developer.foursquare.com. I read and used

```
oauth_key = 'my_key'
oauth_secret = 'my_secret'

oauth = Foursquare::OAuth.new(oauth_key, oauth_secret)

request_token = oauth.request_token.token
request_secret = oauth.request_token.secret
```

also I have tried;

```
oauth_key = 'my_key'
oauth_secret = 'my_secret'

oauth = Foursquare::OAuth.new(oauth_key, oauth_secret)

oauth.request_token(:oauth_callback => "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token")

request_token = oauth.request_token.token
request_secret = oauth.request_token.secret
```

but when I run my project I get "OAuth::Unauthorized (404 Not Found):" error. How can I solve it? Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: when you get the oauth key are you storing in your db

Comment: No I don't store anything to my db. should I store key and secret?

Comment: This question seems more like a 'forum' posting of someone needing help, perhaps there are library bugs in play. Is there another venue for getting help on this?